# Convert a list of lists (objects) into a list of strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop, object, nested-lists

Is there a way i can convert this:

```
listofadds = [(1, 'fakestreet', 'city', 'ab12 1ab'), (2, 'sillystreet', 'othercity', 'dc12 4ef')]
```

into this:

```
['1 fakestreet city ab12 1ab', '2 sillystreet othercity dc12 4ef']
```

So far i have been able to convert one of them, by turning the integer into a string and then concatenating:

```
f = listofadds[0]
h = [str(i) for i in f]
g = ' '
s = g.join((h))
>>> '1 fakestreet city ab12 1ab'
```

But i am not sure how to use a for loop to successfully repeat this for the next one, and any others that appear in the original list!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listofadds = [(1, 'fakestreet', 'city', 'ab12 1ab'), (2, 'sillystreet', 'othercity', 'dc12 4ef')]
new_list = [' '.join([str(i) for i in curr]) for curr in listofadds]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example:

```
new_list = []
for object in listofadds:
    element_string = " ".join([str(element) for element in object])
    new_list.append(element_string)
```